# The name of this part of a spoon

Tags: word-request

What do we call the element that is between the *bowl* and the *fiddle-shaped end of the handle*?

I found several names: **neck, shoulder, transition, curve, bend, bolster**. But which one is correct?

[image: a spoon]

Comment: I don't know that one term is any better than the others.  It isn't something that anybody would normally refer to.  The only people using the term would be spoon makers.  It probably has a number of terms referring to its function or nature.  You would have an even harder time if you were talking about a spork.

Comment: @fixer1234 Spork or spoon, the idea is the same. If I want someone to bend it harder at that place, how do I say it?

Comment: I would probably use "neck" because that's a pretty universal term and people would know what I was referring to.  The other terms would be ambiguous (and I've never heard "bolster" used in that context, but I'm not a spoon expert).

Comment: I've been speaking English my whole live (well, since I was one year old or so anyway) and it never occurred to me that that part of a spoon even *had* a name...

Comment: @stangdon How would tell Neo where the spoon should bend?

Comment: @SovereignSun - I would probably just tell him to "bend the spoon"!  If I absolutely had to be specific, I would say "the handle", and if that wasn't specific enough, I *guess* I would say "the neck".

Comment: Now we need to merge two answers and I'll accept that!

Comment: I've learned something I did not know and had never really thought about. Very enjoyable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is often referred to as *the stem* of the spoon. [Here are lots of quotes from Google for "stem of a spoon".](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?source=search_app&gfe_rd=cr&ei=XSjuWPOqHsbv8Ae-iZj4Bg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22stem+of+the+spoon%22&start=80)

Here is a relevant definition for *stem* from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stem)

> 2. A long, thin supportive or main section of something.
>
>    > ‘*the main stem of the wing feathers*’

The word *stem* is mainly used for plants:

[image]

But we can use it to refer to any long thin supporting part of an object. Wine glasses have stems in English:

[image]

Here is an image entitled ["anatomy of a spoon"](http://www.ascasonline.org/articolomarz94.html):

[image]

---

<sup>**Picture references:**</sup>

<sup>1. [First-learn.com](http://www.first-learn.com/how-plants-grow.html)</sup>

<sup>2. [Fabulous Ladies Wine Society](https://fabulousladieswinesociety.com/how-to-choose-the-right-wine-glass/)</sup>

<sup>3. [Association of small collectors of antique silver](http://www.ascasonline.org/articolomarz94.html)</sup>

Comment: I agree that stem is the correct answer and can provide two additional sources
http://www.925-1000.com/a_spoonanatomy.html and 
http://www.antiques-art-collectibles.com/collectible/cutlery_pattern.htm

I would also note that most people only talk about the handle or the bowl. For example when people describe the spoon bending that Uri Geller did, they would refer to the spot of bending as where the handle meets the bowl. Also, in the Wikipedia entry for types of spoons, many spoons are described as having a long handle when technically they have a long stem.

Comment: Stem might be technically correct, but it is ambiguous when you have a continuous handle like the spoon in the question.  Where does the handle end and the stem begin?  Is there a shoulder?  etc.  A term like "neck" may not be technically correct, but people would understand it as a relatively shot, narrow area connecting the handle to the bowl.

Comment: @fixer1234 It might be a pond thing. It's just the word that automatically came to mind as a Brit.

Comment: @Araucaria That's possibly what I'm looking for, however, I'm starting to think that **"stem"** is used only for vertical object, while a spoon is an exception? If we take a knife for instance, will it also have a stem? And fixer1234 spotted an interesting point.

Comment: @SovereignSun No, it's used for lots of horizontalish things, like pipes for example :)

Comment: @SovereignSun  Fixer's point is kind of right. If you break the stem you obviously break the handle because the stem is *part* of the handle. So you wouldn't be bothered about specifying that it was the thin narrow bit of the handle in most circumstances. However, if you *do* need to specify which part, *stem* is the word you need. Suppose for example you are giving someone instructions for [applying eye make-up](http://www.lifehacker.guru/8-makeup-hacks-every-girl-should-keep-their-eye-on/) (see second section). You'll need to say *stem* here. If you say *handle* people will ...

Comment: @SovereignSun ...put the violin-shaped bit against their eye. And that wouldn't work. The same thing would apply if you wanted to explain *how* to bend a spoon to someone who hadn't seen it done. Much better to say to rub the stem of the spoon, rather than the handle! [See here, for example](http://www.goodvibeuniversity.com/public/Spoon_bending_fun.cfm) where the writer says "*While visiting your place of peace, hold the stem of the spoon (near the bowl) with your thumb and index finger*" :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 I think you've shown a problem with using "neck" in your own description.  You say people would know it's " a relatively shot, narrow area connecting the handle to the bowl" assuming you meant short, not shot, I would disagree.  The stem isn't short, the shoulder is the short part.  The stem is the elongated thin area between shoulder and handle.  When you say neck people may think you mean shoulder, because it is a shorter area connecting the bowl to the stem.  Stem implies it is the _long_ narrow part, which seems more correct in context.  This seems closer to what OP wanted.

Comment: @JMac Based on OP including "curve" and "bend" alongside that image, I have the feeling they didn't mean the stem and accepted this answer too quickly

Comment: @Izkata "What do we call the element that is between the bowl and the fiddle-shaped end of the handle?"  "Curve" seems to be one of the options because the entire length of it has a curve.  It really sounds like stem is exactly what they meant.  The long area between the bowl and the tip.

Comment: @fixer1234 In the Matrix is Neo bending it at the neck, the stem, the shoulder?

Comment: @Araucaria, For me, "the word that automatically came to mind as a Brit" was "neck". :)

Comment: @w3d Yes, that sound like a good word too! I did start my post with "It is often referred to as ... ." There are probably several possible answers/words. :)

Comment: On a side note - I found it interesting that the *anatomy of a spoon* used *tip* as the label for *both* ends of the spoon, instead of just the end near the bowl.

Answer (score 11):

This seems to vary, perhaps dependent on dialect and/or the particular shape of the spoon. Merriam-Webster's visual dictionary would call the narrowest part the [***neck***](http://www.visualdictionaryonline.com/food-kitchen/kitchen/silverware/spoon.php) and the rest, including the "fiddle-shaped end", all just *handle*.

Here is an image of M-W's diagram:

[image: Diagram of spoon lying concave side up, showing parts from left to right: tip, bowl (top)/back (bottom), neck, handle]

This diagram shows a spoon much like the one in the OP's example, narrowest just at the bowl and widening from there. It lacks the fancy, wider bit just where the bowl meets the handle that is labelled "shoulder" in a diagram in another answer. For this simple type of spoon I would be inclined to talk about the *neck* as the narrowest bit; if there were a "shoulder" then perhaps *stem* would make more sense.

My impression is that neck is the more common term in the US for flatware,  perhaps because in the realm of kitchen terminology *stems* naturally bring to mind *stemware* (i.e. wine glasses, champagne flutes, etc.) or possibly because we have more examples of the shoulder-less kind of spoon (all plastic spoons, for example). It's hard to judge this objectively because it's just not a common thing to talk about, but I note that there are about [24 hits in Google Books for "neck of the spoon"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22neck%20of%20the%20spoon%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=HBLtWMj3HqfVjwTs4pvICw&start=20&sa=N&biw=1344&bih=712&dpr=1.25) and about [17 for "stem of the spoon"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stem%20of%20the%20spoon%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=LhLtWNaSL5-9jwTNgaPwBA&start=10&sa=N&biw=1344&bih=712&dpr=1.25); I would guess that these skew toward US publishers, though I haven't actually examined all the results.

---

Edit: Here is an image of a Google Ngram comparing "neck of the spoon" and "stem of the spoon" in the [American corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neck%20of%20the%20spoon%2Cstem%20of%20the%20spoon&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cneck%20of%20the%20spoon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstem%20of%20the%20spoon%3B%2Cc0) and [British corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=neck%20of%20the%20spoon%2Cstem%20of%20the%20spoon&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstem%20of%20the%20spoon%3B%2Cc0), respectively, in case that platform is more stable than the regular Google Books search (which doesn't always return the same answers for an apparently identical search). The Ngrams do in fact suggest that "neck" is more common in the modern US, while "stem" is the only choice in the UK, but the n is so low that I would only call it suggestive, not definitive.

[image: Google Ngram comparing "neck of the spoon" and "stem of the spoon" in the American corpus and British corpus, respectively, both from 1900-2000; "neck" overtakes "stem" in the American Ngram around 1980 except for a small dip in the early nineties, but is not found in the UK corpus at all.]

Comment: Merriam-Webster is obviously the ultimate authority on spoons.  This is clearly the correct answer.  :-)

Comment: "neck is the more common term in the US" - As a native British English speaker, "neck" would be my term of choice for this part of the spoon as well. (I'm no spoon expert, just a commoner.)

Comment: +1 from me :) [In terms of Google books, though, there are no hits for "neck of the spoon". None of those returns actually have the phrase "neck of the spoon" in if we actually look at them (that doesn't really mean very much!). But there are several instances in the returns for "stem of the spoon", though (and that doesn't mean very much either!)]

Comment: @Araucaria Interesting. Did you follow my links, or do your own search? Either way, it may be evidence of an Atlantic divide, since presumably Google's search bubble is preferencing UK results for you and US results for me. Oh, and also did you note that the links were to the last page of legit results for each search? The actually-visible results are all on the earlier pages, and later "pages" return a "did not match any book results" error.

Comment: @1006a I did both!!! I can still only get one result from Googebooks for "neck of the spoon".

Comment: @Araucaria Very odd, unless it is indeed a bubble effect. I'm going to paste in a screenshot of my first page of results (split across two screens) so you can see if any of those books show up in your search; I'll probably take it back out eventually as I don't know how much it adds to the answer, but now you've got me curious!

Comment: @1006a OK, I look forward to it :) (got some popcorn)

Comment: @1006a Wow, that's weird. I'll stick my one into a comment on chat. Would be interesting to see whether you see what I see ...

Comment: @1006a Have you been to chat yet?

Comment: @Araucaria How do I find you in chat?

Comment: I've just stuck up the results I got in a different answer box. Let us know when you've seen them and I'll delete it! :-)